# Get random line at txt file. Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

```
 <cffile action="read" file="#ExpandPath( './text.txt' )#" variable="pag">
```

How to display a random line from a file on the screen?
This txt file contains lines 10k.
Thank

Answer (score 4):

Treat the file as a chr(10) delimited list.  Use `listToArray` to convert it to an array.  Use `arrayLen` to get the number of lines and `randRange` to get a random number.  Then output the line.

Comment: *a chr(10) delimited list* That may result in extra characters. Line delimiters vary by o/s.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
<cfscript>
pag = FileOpen(ExpandPath( './text.txt' ), "read"); 
counter = 0;
randomLine = randRange(1, 10000);
while(NOT FileisEOF(myfile)) { 
    counter++;
    if (counter==randomLine) {
        x = FileReadLine(pag); // read line 
        WriteOutput("#x#");
        break;
    }
} 
FileClose(pag); 
</cfscript>
```

It's not very efficient to do it that way, and also it relies on you knowing the number of lines in the file. If you need to do it multiple times, then it would be much better to read the file once and store each line in a database or persistent storage scope. You could then quite easily grab any record from it. For example:

```
<cfscript>  
// read the file once
pag = FileOpen(ExpandPath( './text.txt' ), "read"); 
lines = [];
while(NOT FileisEOF(myfile)) { 
    arrayAppend(lines, FileReadLine(pag)); // read line 
} 
FileClose(pag);

// store the `lines` in a persistent scope or db etc
// here I'm using application scope as a simple example
application.filelines = lines;
</cfscript>
```

Then you can grab a random line without re-reading the file

```
<cfscript>
totalLines = arrayLen(application.filelines);
randomLine = randRange(1, totalLines);

writeOutput(application.filelines[randomLine]);
</cfscript>
```